# Problema com solicitação Ajax no JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, angularjs, apache-cordova

Tenho uma aplicação mobile em desenvolvimento utilizando `Cordova`, que realiza um select no meu BD externo e verifica com os dados do mobile assim sabendo se existe alguma alteração nos dado.

O estou utilizando um requerimento via `AJAX`. O funcionamento correto seria, o app verifica se existe alteração caso tenha algo diferente ele executa um `UPDATE` no meu BD mobile, depois ele teria que montar uma tabela com as informações para o usuário visualizar.

Porém ele não espera o retorno do `AJAX`para saber se existe alterações,ele simplesmente chama a função e monta a tabela. Quando eu inspeciono linha a linha ele até espera o retorno do AJAX, mas não deixa ser realizada a chamada da função para fazer o `UPDATE` no BD mobile.

Segue abaixo o meu código:

```
atualizarTabela: function (tx, results) {
    var len = results.rows.length;
    if (conectado == 1) { Verificação se existe conexão com internet
        for (var cont = 0; cont < len; cont++) {
            var prazo = results.rows.item(cont).prazo;
            var statusBD = results.rows.item(cont).status;
            var nomeDepartamento = results.rows.item(cont).nomeDepartamento;
            var protocolo = results.rows.item(cont).protocolo;
            var serviceURL = "http://192.168.0.104:18376/Solicitacao/SelectAtualizacao";
            var parametros = { id: protocolo }
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: serviceURL,
                data: parametros,
                async: false, // Tentei colocar async false mas não resolveu
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("Retorno Ajax ok");
                    if (data[0].prazo != prazo || data[0].status != statusBD || data[0].id_departamento != nomeDepartamento) { //Verifica se existe alterações
                        db.transaction(select, errorCB, sucess);
                        function select(tx) { //Este seria o meu Update no bd local
                            tx.executeSql('UPDATE ouvidoria11 set prazo = "' + data[0].prazo + '", status = "' + data[0].status + '", nomeDepartamento = "' + data[0].nomeDepartamento + '" WHERE protocolo="' + protocolo + '"');
                            app.selectDB(); 
                        }
                        function errorCB() {
                            alert("ERROCB");
                        }
                        function sucess() {
                            alert("Atualizado!");
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        app.montarSolicitacao(tx, results); 
    }
    else { //Caso não tenha internet, monta tabela sem verificação de Atualização
        app.montarSolicitacao(tx, results);
    }
},
```

Comment: Como o @TobyMosque disse o trecho `app.montarSolicitacao(tx, results); ` deve estar dentro do método `success` do AJAX, creio que após a linha `db.transaction(select, errorCB, sucess);`.

Answer (score 2):

você tem que montar a solicitação dentro da função de callback do AJAX.

```
atualizarTabela: function (tx, results) {
    var len = results.rows.length;
    if (conectado == 1) { Verificação se existe conexão com internet
        for (var cont = 0; cont < len; cont++) {
            var prazo = results.rows.item(cont).prazo;
            var statusBD = results.rows.item(cont).status;
            var nomeDepartamento = results.rows.item(cont).nomeDepartamento;
            var protocolo = results.rows.item(cont).protocolo;
            var serviceURL = "http://192.168.0.104:18376/Solicitacao/SelectAtualizacao";
            var parametros = { id: protocolo }
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: serviceURL,
                data: parametros,
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("Retorno Ajax ok");                    
                    if (data[0].prazo != prazo || data[0].status != statusBD || data[0].id_departamento != nomeDepartamento) { //Verifica se existe alterações
                        db.transaction(select, errorCB, sucess);
                        function select(tx) { //Este seria o meu Update no bd local
                            tx.executeSql('UPDATE ouvidoria11 set prazo = "' + data[0].prazo + '", status = "' + data[0].status + '", nomeDepartamento = "' + data[0].nomeDepartamento + '" WHERE protocolo="' + protocolo + '"');
                            app.selectDB(); 
                        }
                        function errorCB() {
                            alert("ERROCB");
                        }
                        function sucess() {
                            alert("Atualizado!");
                        }
                    }
                    app.montarSolicitacao(tx, results); 
                }
            });
        }        
    }
    else { //Caso não tenha internet, monta tabela sem verificação de Atualização
        app.montarSolicitacao(tx, results);
    }
},
```

Comment: Realmente funcionou obrigado, porem se eu coloco dentro da `function sucess(){}` ele não funciona, não esta chamando a função `select()` como posso fazer com que seja chamada? @KaduAmaral @TobyMosque